# Pidgin & Lync - Some buddies are not recognized

Tags: pidgin

I'm running RHEL 6 and using Pidgin to connect to the corporate Lync server.  Overall it works quite well.  My problem is that, apparently randomly, some of my 'buddies' are not properly looked up from the Lync server.  In most cases I can add a new buddy by using their email address.  Pidgin then goes and looks up all kinds of details, including name and status.  For a small handful of people who I attempt to add as a buddy, none of that happens.  I get no status or name, and the person is just listed in my buddy list as 'sip:their_email@our_company.com'.  I can delete the buddy and re-add always with the same result.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has seen this and/or has any suggestions.

Comment: I'll just add that this means I can never IM that person because they're always marked 'Offline'.  They can IM me, but not they other way round.  And even in the chat window, I don't see their real name, still just 'sip:email...'

Comment: I get something similar pretty consistently with Pidgin 2.10.7 and SIPE 1.16.1. I'll add buddies fine, then the next time I start up Pidgin, buddies aren't saved, and all the Lync/SIPE/Office365 buddies are gone again. No problems with other protocols. This is under Windows 7, but I'd expect it not to be an OS-related issue.